# Download Manager Working in Android Lollipop But Doesn't Work in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am downloading file from server but the same code works in lollipop but doesn't work in marshmallow. Whats the issue?

I have seen in marshmallow that when a permission is required it popup's within the app. Is it the problem? I am only guessing. Also please check the directory

```
public void myDownload(String myURL, String title, String year, String branch, String section) {

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(myURL));
    request.setTitle("File Download");
    request.setDescription("Downloading....");

    //request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(myURL, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(myURL));

    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/sdcard/KiiTTimeTableData/" + year + "/" + branch + "/" + section + "/", nameOfFile);
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Whats the issue?

At minimum, you are misusing `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()`.

First, [that does not take an arbitrary string as the first parameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). It takes one of the `Environment.DIRECTORY_*` constants, such as `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`.

Second, even if it *did* support an arbitrary location, a device does not have to have an `/sdcard` directory.